# Do I have to write all the possibilities?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I made a memory game

Fishes (it's buttons ) display on the screen and stop,then other fishes ( a wrong fishes ) display on the stage.After a while stops all the scene and player make guess ( click ) right fishes.

For example if player clicked 2 false and 1 true button,or 2 true and 1 false, this results in a loss for the player.And if clicked true 3 fis then this results in a win for the player.

But problem is I have to write code for all possibilities.How can I do as simple.

```
var clicked1:Boolean = false;
var clicked2:Boolean = false;
var clicked3:Boolean = false;
var clicked4:Boolean = false;
var clicked5:Boolean = false;
var clicked6:Boolean = false;
 
 
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fish1);
function fish1(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    clicked1 = true;
    checkButtonsone()
    }
 
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redButton1a);
function redButton1a(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    clicked2 = true;
    checkButtonsone()
    }
 
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redButton12);
function redButton12(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    clicked3 = true;
    checkButtonsone()
    }
 
btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redButton22);
function redButton22(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    clicked4 = true;
    checkButtonsone()
    }
 
btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redButton32);
function redButton32(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    clicked5 = true;
    checkButtonsone()
    }
 
btn6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redButton42);
function redButton42(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    clicked6 = true;
    checkButtonsone()
    }
 
//Check true and false

function checkButtonsone():void
var correctcombine = false;
var falsecombine1 = false;
 
{
if(clicked1 && clicked2 && clicked3 )
    {
    correctcombine = true;
    }
 
    {
    if(falsetiklandi && falsetiklandi && falsetiklandi){
       falsecombine1 = true;
    }
 
///Go to true or false
 
if(correctcombine == true)
 
            {
            gotoAndStop(3)
        }   

        if(falsecombine1 == true)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2)
        }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buttons:Array = [fish1,fish2,fish3,fish4,fish5,fish6];
var correct:Array = [true,true,true,false,false,false];
var answers:Array = [false,false,false,false,false,false];
var clicksLeft:int = 3;

for each (var aButton:InteractiveObject in buttons)
{
    aButton.addEventListener(MouseEvemt.CLICK, onButton);
}

function onButton(e:Event):void
{
    var aButton:InteractiveObject = e.currentTarget as InteractiveObject;
    var anIndex:int = buttons.indexOf(aButton);

    // Remove click handler to avoid unnecessary handling.
    aButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvemt.CLICK, onButton);

    // Check answers.
    answers[anIndex] = true;

    clicksLeft--;

    if (clicksLeft > 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var aWrong:Boolean = false;
    var aComplete:Boolean = true;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < correct.length; i++)
    {
        if (answers[i] != correct[i])
        {
            if (answers[i])
            {
                // answers[i] == true and correct[i] == false
                aWrong = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // answers[i] == false and correct[i] == true
                // That means all correct buttons are not pressed yet.
                aComplete = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (aWrong)
    {
        // User failed case.
    }
    else if (aComplete)
    {
        // User win case.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check my answer please @Organis

Comment: I edited mine so it should do what you want: clicking first 3 fishes will be a correct answer.

Comment: I already fix problem for correct fish..but when I click wrong fish first (only once ) it's go to frame.For example: Fish1+fish2+Fish3= Goframe it's work.But When I click wrong first for example :Fish4 it's go to frame.it's wrong because not clicked other wrongs yet.

Comment: So, you want combos? 1+2+3 and 4+5+6?

Comment: actually I need 4 combo.

Any true fish + Any true fish + Any true fish = Correct....
Any true fish + Any False fish + Any true fish = Wrong....
Any true fish + Any False fish + Any False fish = Wrong....
Any False fish+Any False fish+Any False fish = Wrong.........if I can do this then I don't have to write code for all possibilities.it's about 20 possibilities.

Comment: Can't you just break it to 2 cases? True + true + true = correct, anything else = wrong.

Comment: Yes,this really what I'm looking for.How can I do that ?

Comment: My code works exactly like that, with the only difference it does not wait for 3 clicks. So you need that user clicks exactly 3 times before figuring correct vs wrong?

Comment: I added a click counter that allows 3 clicks and only then goes for decision part. That main problem is, you're not thinking algorithmically. Please learn algorithms for else (AS3 or not) each problem will be a painful struggle for you.

Comment: Thank you Origins.I will follow your advice.But it's not work.Because if I clicked 1 times a button,it's go to the frame anyway.Also didn't work true button's.I think this is a little bug.if you think I'm doing wrong something.Here is my fla.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDzq4EkhjKwVnBlZUt2TTc2c2c/view

Comment: Yep, I messed with the counter in a wrong way. Fixed it.

Comment: Finally :) Thank you again Organis.This is exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code, so it becomes more easy in this way:

You can call the same event linked to different buttons and then you can evaluate the currentTarget property of event (passed as parameter)

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeClicked);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeClicked);
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeClicked);
btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeClicked);
btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeClicked);
btn6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeClicked);

function changeClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
   switch(event.currentTarget.id) {
       case "btn1": {
           clicked1 = true;
           break;
       }
       case "btn2": {
           clicked2 = true;
           break;
       }
       case "btn3": {
           clicked3 = true;
           break;
       }           
       case "btn4": {
           clicked4 = true;
           break;
       }
       case "btn5": {
           clicked5 = true;
           break;
       }
       case "btn6": {
           clicked6 = true;
           break;
       }
   }
    checkButtonsone();
}
```

You must overwrite your code with mine from your:

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fish1);
```

until line before

```
//Check true and false
```

Further optimization can be instead use 6 different variables, you can use an Array or ArrayCollection or you can define an object where you can encapsulated your different click.

**UPDATE**

You can define an `ActionScript` object named (for example) `QuizLevel` as follow:

```
[Bindable]
public class QuizLevel {
    private var _levelNo:int;
    private var _value1:Boolean;
    private var _value2:Boolean;
    private var _value3:Boolean;
    private var _value4:Boolean;
    private var _value5:Boolean;
    private var _value6:Boolean;

    // Here you put getter and setter
}
```

When you start a new quiz level, you define your matrix.

If only three are true you have a `QuizLevel` object instantiated as follow:

```
levelNo = 1
value1 = true
value2 = true
value3 = true
value4 = false
value5 = false
value6 = false
```

In your MXML definition you can write (insteead of button, use check box and one only button to submit your choose)

I've created a `s:WindowedApplication` (by AIR but is the same for Flash Player and others) and I've defined a preinitialized event in the `s:WindowedApplication`

```
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        [Bindable]
        private var quizLevel:QuizLevel = new QuizLevel();

        private var check1:Boolean = false;
        private var check2:Boolean = false;
        private var check3:Boolean = false;
        private var check4:Boolean = false;
        private var check5:Boolean = false;
        private var check6:Boolean = false;

        protected function windowedapplication1_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            quizLevel = new QuizLevel();
            quizLevel.levelNo = 1;
            quizLevel.value1 = true;
            quizLevel.value2 = true;
            quizLevel.value3 = true;
            quizLevel.value4 = false;
            quizLevel.value5 = false;
            quizLevel.value6 = false;
        }

        protected function changeClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var checkBox:CheckBox = event.currentTarget as CheckBox;
            switch(event.currentTarget.id) {
                case "chk1":{
                    check1 = checkBox.selected;
                    break;
                }
                case "chk2":{
                    check2 = checkBox.selected;
                    break;
                }
                case "chk3":{
                    check3 = checkBox.selected;
                    break;
                }
                case "chk4":{
                    check4 = checkBox.selected;
                    break;
                }
                case "chk5":{
                    check5 = checkBox.selected;
                    break;
                }
                case "chk6":{
                    check6 = checkBox.selected;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        protected function btnSubmit_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var message:String = "";
            if (quizLevel.value1 == check1 &&
                quizLevel.value2 == check2 &&
                quizLevel.value3 == check3 &&
                quizLevel.value4 == check4 &&
                quizLevel.value5 == check5 &&
                quizLevel.value6 == check6) {
                message = "It'OK";
            } else {
                message = "You're wrong";
            }

            Alert.show(message);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:CheckBox id="chk1" label="Choose #1" click="changeClicked(event)" />
    <s:CheckBox id="chk2" label="Choose #2" click="changeClicked(event)" />
    <s:CheckBox id="chk3" label="Choose #3" click="changeClicked(event)" />
    <s:CheckBox id="chk4" label="Choose #4" click="changeClicked(event)" />
    <s:CheckBox id="chk5" label="Choose #5" click="changeClicked(event)" />
    <s:CheckBox id="chk6" label="Choose #6" click="changeClicked(event)" />
    <s:Button id="btnSubmit" label="Submit" click="btnSubmit_clickHandler(event)" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: Hello I'm sorry I very new on AS3 and I check some switch video but not understand clearly..Can you give me a example worikng code for just one combine ? Thanks.

Comment: I have to write 20 combine already and I will have to more for next level's.But if I can make something like..

" button 1 ( it's true) , button 2 ( it's true),button 3 ( it's true),button 4 ( it's false),button 5 ( it's false),button 6 ( it's false),

I just need 4 combination so it's easy then write all combinations.

(True,True,True) = Correct
(True,False,True) = Wrong
(True,False,False) = Wrong
(False,False,False) = Wrong